# Using SQL Server Intergration Services (SSIS) can you read a file from a FileStream column in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to create a tool that I can upload different types of files "csv", Excel, XML and load those files into a FileStream column in the database as "Source" untouched over the web.  Then using SSIS on the server I want to create a package that will process that file to be loaded into other tables to be used by the web application.

Is it possible to have SSIS read a file from FileStream column? if so how?

Answer (score 1):

In the data flow, you'd use an Import Column transform (usage described here: http://agilebi.com/cs/blogs/jwelch/archive/2008/02/02/importing-files-using-ssis.aspx) to pull the file into the data flow. It brings it in as type DT_IMAGE, which can be written to a FILESTREAM column, which is of type varbinary(MAX), using the OLE DB Destination.